# Низкое разрешение экрана в Debian

Tags: linux, debian, gnome, x11, radeon

Установил *Debian 8.3*. После установки получил разрешение экрана `640x480`.

Как это поправить?

Видео карта ATI Radeon HD 5700. Скачал с AMD драйвера, но установщик запускается в графическом виде и там не видно кнопок. Я выбираю пункт `Install` и просто нажимаю `Enter` вслепую, но получаю ошибку:

> vcdk is missing, installation aborted.

Comment: Пакеты fglrx и fglrx-amdcccle установлены?

Comment: Вы пробовали `xrandr`? [См.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490019/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0/490020#490020)