# Низкое разрешение экрана

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо

Внезапно компьютер начал загружаться с низким разрешением монитора.

Симптомы:
GRUB загружается с низким разрешением.
Потом Ubuntu 14.04 загружается с низким разрешением.
`Параметры системы` -> `Настройка экранов`  говорит «Неизвестный монитор» и максимальное разрешение у него 1024 x 768.

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0*
   800x600        60.3     56.2
   848x480        60.0
   640x480        59.9
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Windows тоже загружается с низкой резолюцией, но дает поменять на нормальную.

Я подозреваю, что поломалась какая-то компонента оборудования, но если Windows может это исправить, то и в Ubuntu это можно починить?

Comment: очень похоже что монитор перестал отдавать о себе корректные сведения. Такое бывает, если поврежден VGA кабель или разъем. Обычно страдает разъем, ножка запала или замялась, но могут быть и другие причины. В этом случае видеоадаптер не может определить родное разрешение и выставляет "универсальное и безопасное", что-то вроде 800х600.

Comment: Не помогло! Помогите! sergey@sergey-pc ~/web/domains/hlamada $ xrandr Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2784 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767 LVDS1 connected 864x486+1920+594 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm 864x486 60.00* 640x480 59.94 DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) HDMI1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1060mm x 626mm 1366x768 59.79 + 1920x1080 60.00*+ 50.00 59.94 30.00 25.00 24.00 29.97 23.98 1920x1080i 60.00 50.00 59.94 1680x1050 59.88 1600x900 60.00 1280x1024 75.02 60.02 1440x900 59.90 1280x800 59.9

Comment: @Lancer, попробуйте чуть пошевелить кабель монитора возле монитора. Если это помогло, то причина в повреждении кабеля, как описано в первом комментарии (от @rdorn). Если у вас не получилось решить проблему, вам стоит  задать вопрос, и дать там всю историю, как возникла проблема и что вы пробовали, и что решение моего вопроса не помогло (иначе ваш вопрос могут посчитать дубликатом). Удачи!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Установка разрешения монитора для сессии

(Эта часть решения найдена в [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19954/how-to-set-the-monitor-to-its-native-resolution-which-is-not-listed-in-the-resol?lq=1).
О команде `xrandr` можно почитать по-русски [здесь](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29),
а конкретнее по данному вопросу [здесь](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr_%28%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9%29#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BA_.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.81.D1.83.D1.82.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D1.83.D1.8E.D1.89.D0.B8.D1.85_.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B6.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.BE.D0.B2).)

Сначала нужно запустить команду `cvt` и задать ей нужное разрешение.
Я не помнила, какое разрешение было раньше. Для того, чтобы это узнать, я посмотрела размер обоев для рабочего стола.

```
cvt 1440 900 60
# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

Нам нужно то, что написано после слова Modeline.
Копируем это в `xrandr --newmode` (создать новый режим):

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
```

Теперь добавляем новый режим:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00
```

(название монитора "VGA1" берется из вывода `xrandr` без параметров, как в вопросе)

на этом этапе у меня поменялось разрешение, хотя в документации предлагают запустить еще одну команду.

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900_60.00
```

Последние три команды меняют разрешение экрана в текущей сессии.

### 2. Постоянное разрешение

Внимание! Если в решении, приведенном ниже, что-то не сработает, то графический интерфейс не загрузится и появится черный экран.
Вы можете нажать `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Fn`, где *n* от 1 до 6, чтобы вызвать виртуальную консоль, и там откатить или что-то изменить (например, с помощью команды `sudo nano`).

Итак, лучшее решение, что я нашла:
Создаем скрипт с этими тремя командами `xrandr`

```
xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1440x900_60.00
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1440x900_60.00
```

например, такой командой:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/bin/lightdmxrandr.sh &
```

Затем делаем его исполняемым:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/lightdmxrandr.sh
```

Теперь добавляем строку

```
display-setup-script=/usr/bin/lightdmxrandr.sh
```

в файл `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf`, например, с помощью команды

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

Теперь LightDM будет запускать этот скрипт перед X Windows.

Вторая часть основана на [этом вопросе](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445957/why-dont-my-lightdm-conf-edits-affect-my-desktop-screen-resolution/446050#446050).

Comment: я вас умоляю, дайте мне этот скрипт. Я не умею его делать, не понимаю вообще ничего в этом, я только начал пользоваться! Я ели смог команды выше сделать. У меня всё идентичное кроме "VGA1" у меня "VGA-0". ПРОШУ, ПОМОГИТЕ!

Comment: @Brawl Stars BrunoGuillou, скрипт  - это те 3 строчки, что  начинаются на xrandr. У вас получилось открыть  редактор с помощью gksudo gedit? Если нет, то напишите файл в sudo nano.