# Экран в зеленых тонах

Tags: железо

Монитор загружается в зеленых тонах, как будто у него отключены красные и синие пиксели.
Это заметно уже на стадии GRUBа. 
Потом как Ubuntu, так и  Windows продолжают показывать зеленым.

Однако, если нажать на кнопку регулировки на самом мониторе, появляется прекрасное цветное меню, с красным и синим!

Гамма на Ubuntu:

```
$ xgamma
-> Red  1.000, Green  1.000, Blue  1.000
```

Подобная проблема уже возникала у меня некоторое время назад, только экран после загрузки был в синих тонах, без красных и зеленых пикселей.  Тогда я, сразу как это увидела, нажала на кнопку <s>Паника</s> Перезагрузка. Цвета стали нормальными, но разрешение экрана стало низким. В тот раз  эту проблему мне удалось [решить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490019/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). Теперь перезагрузка ничего не меняет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашелся неожиданно на сайте [apple.se](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139302). Я **пошевелила провод**, как там предложили, экран из зеленого стал синим, а потом стал показывать нормально. И с тех пор больше меня не беспокоил!

Комментарий [rdorn](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/198316/rdorn)а из [вопроса про низкое разрешение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490019/%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0) с объяснением возможных причин такого поведения:

> очень похоже что монитор перестал отдавать о себе корректные сведения. Такое бывает, если поврежден VGA кабель или разъем. Обычно страдает разъем, ножка запала или замялась, но могут быть и другие причины. В этом случае видеоадаптер не может определить родное разрешение и выставляет "универсальное и безопасное", что-то вроде 800х600.